# Make links for each individual database record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make individual links for each individual record.
I have two files:

**index.php**

```
 <?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "pass");
if (!$connect) {
    die("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snippets", $connect);

$ID = ''; 
if( isset( $_GET['ID'])) {
    $ID = $_GET['ID']; 
} 


$sql = "SELECT * FROM lectures";
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
$ID = $record['ID'];
$Name = $record['Name'];

    echo "<div class=\"container\">";
    echo "<div class=\"row\">";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[ID]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Topic]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Name]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Attendance]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\" style=\"display:none;\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Topic]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\" style=\"\">";
            echo "<td> <a href='car.php?id=" . $ID . " '>" . $record['Name'] . "</a> </td>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";


}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

And **car.php**

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "test", "pass");
if (!$connect) {
    die("Can not connect:" . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("snippets", $connect);



$ID = ''; 
if( isset( $_GET['ID'])) {
    $ID = $_GET['ID']; 
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lectures WHERE ID = '$ID' ";
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
$ID = $record['ID'];
$Name = $record['Name'];

    echo "<div class=\"container\">";
    echo "<div class=\"row\">";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[ID]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Topic]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Name]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Attendance]</p>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"col-md-2\" style=\"display:none;\">";
            echo "<p>$record[Topic]</p>";
        echo "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";


}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

When I click on the link, the page is empty. If I put a value (eg: 2) in `ID = '2'`, it works. But this will be the value for all links.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore as they are deprecated and in the newly released PHP 7.0 deleted. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Also when handling user input use [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), that makes your query a lot safer against SQL injections.

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you work in linux you should write your `ID` param in capital case, so you should replace this:

```
echo "<td> <a href='car.php?id=" . $ID . " '>" . $record['Name'] . "</a> </td>";
```

by this:

```
echo "<td> <a href='car.php?ID=" . $ID . " '>" . $record['Name'] . "</a> </td>";
```

Comment: I work with phpmyadmin

Comment: Linux has nothing to do with PHP lettercase syntax. That only applies for file/folder naming conventions.

Comment: that isn't my downvote btw.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html

Comment: URLs in general are case-sensitive (with the exception of machine names). There may be URLs, or parts of URLs, where case doesn't matter, but identifying these may not be easy. Users should always consider that URLs are case-sensitive

Comment: I know how things work. I worked on many platforms and know the syntax quite well, *thank you*.

Comment: I replace the 'id' with 'ID' , like you said. It works !

Comment: when you pass id in small, then check if( isset( $_GET['ID'])) {, this will return false.